# Format Document (Ctrl+K,Ctrl+D) equivalent in Visual Basic 6

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any equivalent of the VS7/8/9/10 `Edit` -> `Advanced` -> `Format Document` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) function in the Visual Basic 6 IDE?

I've inherited an old codebase and it is messy in places so I'd like to tidy it up.

Comment: I've been looking for something that does CtrlK CtrlD as well, but haven't found anything. The best tool that I've found is MZTools http://www.mztools.com/index.aspx It's come in handy a few times.

Comment: I have MZTools installed - it is VERY handy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an add-in called [Smart Indenter](http://www.oaltd.co.uk/Indenter/Default.htm) which works very well

EDIT: Link is dead but can still be downloaded from [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20180806191001/http://www.oaltd.co.uk/Indenter/Default.htm)

Comment: The link is dead. Did it respawn?

Comment: Still available via Archive.org

Comment: what you got a direct link please?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20180806191001/http://www.oaltd.co.uk/Indenter/Default.htm